# Access variable from controller in angular js without storing it into array

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Suppose I have controller in angular JS 
which has a for loop
ex:

```js
for(i=0;i<10;i++){
  var a = i;
  var b = i+1;
  // like this i have generate variable in for loop in controller 
}
```

```html
This is my HTML Page 
<button ng-click="functionname"> Create table </button>
   <div>
     <tr>
       <td>
          i needs to bind variable here    
       </td>
     </tr>
   </div>
   </ol>
```

I need to create type ahed table which have variable a and variable b in single row,
so total column will create 10.(since loop till 10)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think what you are asking is possible. Instead of looping in the controller i would create a loop in the html then call a factory or function on scope:

```
$scope.model.processVar = function(myVar){
    //proess myvar
    //return variable 
};
```

Then in html:

```
<button ng-click="functionname"> Create table </button>
   <div>
     <tr data-ng-repeat="myVar in [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]">
       <td>
          {{processVar(myVar)}}
       </td>
     </tr>
   </div>
   </ol>
```

Comment: I am using API that generate some info, i am geeting that info into the variable so i needs to show that into tables, could you manage that ( data binding between variable and table.

Comment: second could be store into database and manupulate using ng-repete

Answer (score -1):

You can use the function row.insertCell() to insert rows in a table. 
I create a jsfiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/9fjvLq9c/

html:

```
<div ng-app>
    <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
        <button ng-click="functionname()"> Create table </button>
        <table id="myTable">

        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

code:

```
function Ctrl($scope){
    var table = document.getElementById("myTable");

    $scope.functionname = function(){
        for(i=0;i<10;i++){
            var a = i;
            var b = i+1;
            var row = table.insertRow(0);

            // Insert new cells (<td> elements) at the 1st and 2nd position of the "new" <tr> element:
            var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
            var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);

            // Add some text to the new cells:
            cell1.innerHTML = a;
            cell2.innerHTML = b;
        }
    }
}
```

Are you looking to do anything in specific with the variables in the table?

Comment: Controllers are not supposed to [manipulate DOM](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller).

Comment: @Bpatil, do you want the table to filter based on the text in an input (ie, only show rows where either a or b match the input)? Can yo give us a mockup of what you are looking for?